# Changing axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to change y axis of this plot:

[image: cos_f]

to this:

[image]

so, I would like to have 1 instead from 0 in the middle of y axis.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the middle value of the displayed y-axis to be `1` instead of 0?  And what did you try to make this happen?

Comment: Yes. I updated description.

Comment: How did you obtain the `y` axis? It doesn't make much sense to me.  It starts from 0, goes down by increments of 0.2, then jumps up to 1, then again it goes down by increments of 0.2.

Comment: Judging from the figures, you don't want to "have 1 instead of 0 in the middle of the y axis", you want to completely change the graph!

Comment: @LuisMendo - Yeah this definitely falls under the Mentalist category.  I haven't been able to write a post on Meta yet.  I will as soon as I am able to.

Comment: @rayryeng Did you find a way to (more or less) automatically determine mentalist-like answers?

Comment: @LuisMendo - I have a few suggestions in mind.  One thing would be to take a look at the comments stream of all of the answers overall.  If there is overwhelming activity within a short span of time, this may be possible that more than one person is seeking clarification to the question.  Another possible suggestion is to count how many edits there are with the question and with people answering the question. If there is an overwhelming amount of edits between both, this means that the OP keeps changing the requirements and we have to keep guessing.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Also, scanning for buzz words around the comments stream such as "doesn't make sense" "please clarify" "edit your post", etc. would probably help too!

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, as you can see plot often change from 1 to -1, so this is very unclear if you use standard y axis.

Comment: @rayryeng Good points. However, although I like the idea of a mentalist badge, it still may be hard to detect the "mentalist pattern" automatically. We'll see how the (meta) community takes the proposal!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the graph to focus on only a small set of `y` values and not change any of your data, use [`ylim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html):

```
ylim([0.95 1.05]);
```

This is assuming that your graph is **already open** and want to adjust that graph in focus.  Also, this will adjust the `y`-axis of your plot while maintaining your data to be the same and show the dynamic range to go from 0.95 to 1.05.  Your wording is very unclear, and judging from your plot and your wording, I believe this is what you're after (@LuisMendo - Mentalist).

Comment: Your mentalist abilities are definitely finer than mine!